# Visual Studio Diagnostic Tools shows query variables as SQL_VARIANT. Is it a problem?

Tags: sql, visual-studio

When I use Diagnostic Tools to watch queries that are running during my app, and when I click on the command text and get full text in a new window, I see something like this where variables of the query are defined:

```
--Type and value data was not available for the following variables. Their values have been set to defaults.
DECLARE @p0 AS SQL_VARIANT;
SET @p0 = NULL;
```

It concerns me that the actual query is using some variable like this, that can affect execution plan in a bad way. Is it a real concern or I'm just confused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is using some variable like this, that can affect execution plan in a bad way. Is it a real concern or I'm just confused?

`SQL_VARIANT` has a very high [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), so yes, passing parameters with this type will cause problems. The target columns will have to be converted to `SQL_VARIANT` for comparison, preventing index use and interfering with cardinality estimation.

But as the message from Visual Studio said:

> --Type and value data was not available for the following variables. Their values have been set to defaults.

So that doesn't mean that your app is actually passing parameters using `SQL_VARIANT`.  Only that Visual Studio can't determine the parameter types, so it's defaulting to `SQL_VARIANT` when producing a batch that approximates what the client is sending.

Comment: Thanks @david-browne-microsoft. BTW, do you know any better solution to profile SQL queries in the app, showing passed parameters and execution time?